# matplotlib not changing scatter point colors if they are assigned the first time

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following minimal example, I create 1-point scatter plot and later change color of points in loop using [Collection.set_color](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.Collection.set_color). If I set the color(s) the first time [scatter](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) is called, `set_color` will not change its face color (only edge color), whereas if I don't specify it when the scatterplot is created, face color will change according to `set_color`.

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
coll=scatter([0],[0],s=500,c=[.1]) # omit c=[.1] here to have face color changing later
ion(); show()
for a in linspace(.1,.9):
    coll.set_color(coll.get_cmap()(a))
    draw()
```

Is that a bug, or am I missing something in the documentation?

Comment: yeah, reproduced in win 7 64bit, mpl 1.0.1

Comment: Works as expected here. Win7 32bit, mpl 1.1.0.

Comment: I've run into similar issues with matplotlib - it's like a scatter point can only be assigned a color once and never over-written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is a bug/limitation of that matplotlib version.
I tried the code with:

```
matplotlib 1.0.1 (ActivePython 2.6.7, win7 64bit)           --> reproduced the behavior
matplotlib 1.1.0.dev (ActivePython 3.2.2, winXP, 32bit)     --> works as expected
```

There is also a comment from Avaris saying he gets expected behavior with mpl 1.1.0 (win7, 32bit)

So I recommend you to upgrade your installation if this is possible